# Does JavaScript support <= operator?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, facelets

I am doing this in JavaScript:

```
function doClick() {
  var theValue = document.getElementById("theForm:theField").value;
  var theLength = theValue.length;

  if( theLength <= 3 )  --> Error
  {
    alert('Character length too small.');
  }
}
```

And `thefield` is a JSF component:

```
<h:form id="theForm">
  <h:commandButton id="theField" action="#{theBean.doFunctionA}" onclick="doClick()"/>
```

When I render this in IE, it show me this error:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /viewMetadata/pages/thePage.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 66] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompileViewMetadata(SAXCompiler.java:716)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compileViewMetadata(Compiler.java:126)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1940)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.access$000(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:129)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage$FaceletViewMetadata.createMetadataView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2049)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    ... 52 more
```

If I replace the error line with this:

```
if( theLength == '3' || theLength == '2' || theLength == '1')
```

Then everything is working fine. I don't really understand what is actually happen?

Comment: The operator should work just fine. 1. Are you certain that's all that is on line 66? 2. Are there any hidden characters (maybe you copied/pasted something around there?)

Comment: What happens if you do this: `if( theLength == '3' || theLength == '2' || theLength == '1' || theLength== '0')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the error message:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing 
/viewMetadata/pages/thePage.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 66]
The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

It sounds like it's trying to parse it as XML. You should read up on what escaping you would usually need in JSF, but the first thing to *try* is just escaping it as XML:

```
if (theLength &lt;= 3)
```

When diagnosing the error, it's important to realise that this isn't actually hitting the browser's Javascript engine - the problem is in *generating* the page.